# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: Algorithmic Trading Using Python - Full Course

Tags: python, json

Estoy haciendo este tutorial Algorithmic Trading Using Python - Full Course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfzGZB4HhEE:

Cuando intento ejecutar esta parte del código:

```
final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = my_columns)
for stock in stocks['Ticker']:
    api_url = f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{stock}/quote?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}'
    data = requests.get(api_url).json()
    final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(
        pd.Series(
        [
            stock,
            data['latestPrice'],
            data['marketCap'],
            'N/A'
            ],
        index = my_columns),
        ignore_index=True
    )

final_dataframe
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
    JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 4
      2 for stock in stocks['Ticker']:
      3     api_url = f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{stock}/quote?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}'
----> 4     data = requests.get(api_url).json()
      5     final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(
      6         pd.Series(
      7         [
   (...)
     14         ignore_index=True
     15     )
     17 final_dataframe

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:968, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    966             pass
    967         except JSONDecodeError as e:
--> 968             raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
    970 try:
    971     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
```

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?
muchas gracias

Comment: y el string json ... es lo principal que debe aportar ... y muy probablemente sea el problema ..

Comment: puedes validar que retorna: `data = requests.get(api_url)` sin el `.json()`